# error: No validator could be found for type: java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bean-validation, java-ee-7, hibernate-validator

I'm working on a project that uses bean validation (Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final). My bean has a attribute with the `@Past` annotation.

```
@Past(message = "A data deve estar no passado.")
private LocalDate dataAbertura;
```

But, when the validation occurs I get the following exception:

```
21:46:12,424 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-35) UT005023: Exception handling request to /financeiro/clientes/pessoafisica: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.time.LocalDate.
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:127) [vraptor-4.1.4.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.time.LocalDate.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125) [hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar:5.1.3.Final]
```

What's wrong? Hibernate Validator doesn't support LocalDate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually the issue to refer to is [HV-874](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-874). Hibernate Validator 5.2.x does add support for some of the new Java 8 date/time types. I should stress "some" in this context. In particular `LocalDate` is not supported. The Javadocs of `LocalDate` says:

> This class does not store or represent a time or time-zone. Instead,
>   it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays. It cannot
>   represent an instant on the time-line without additional information
>   such as an offset or time-zone.

Without an instant on the timeline it is not possible to say if a given date is in the part or future. First by attaching a timezone it would be possible to state and answer this question.

If you still think it makes sense in your use case to use the `Past` and `@Future` constraints for `LocalDate` you can always implement your own `ConstraintValidator` for `LocalDate` and register it via XML using a `constraint-definition` element in a constraint mapping file as seen [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-constraints-car).

If you are using Hibernate Validator 5.2, you can also use the Java ServiceLoader approach to register additional `ConstraintValidator` implementations - see [ConstraintDefinitionContributor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#_constraint_definitions_via_literal_serviceloader_literal). The latter is for now a Hibernate Validator specific feature.

Comment: Ok @Hardy, in my case I have to use LocalDate, so I gonna implement my own ConstraintValidator, thanks.

Comment: Nice explanation to create an annotation [here](http://sterl.org/2015/06/java-jsr-validation-for-dates/)

Answer (score 4):

There is a `@Past` annotation in the `javax.validation.constraints` (validation-api-2.0.1.Final)

And it works pretty well for `java.time.LocalDate`

Answer (score 2):

Since LocalDate is still pretty new a lot of libraries don't handle it yet. In the project I am working on I had to write custom user type for LocalDate.

Take a look at this hibernate issue [HHH-8844](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844)

It seems like they have added a new module hibernate-java8 to support java 8's new Date API.

I know the above information is talking about type mapping but the same might hold true to validation.

If there is no out of the box solution you might just have to write your own. See the following page for an example of adding joda time validators, java 8 dates should be similar [link](http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2010/05/providing-bean-validation-support-for.html)