# How do I fix "HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.time.LocalDateTime" javax.validation

Tags: hibernate, java-8, java-time

I have recently update our project from using Joda time to Java 8's java.time.

For the most part, the exercise has been a success; that is to say, it builds! However, some of my tests are failing with:

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could
>   be found for type: java.time.LocalDateTime.

I am using Hibernate 5.1, Hibernate-Validator 5.2.4, Hibernate-java8 version 5.1 and spring version 4.2.0.

I have seen other suggestions that say to replace @NotEmpty anotation with @NotNull. I have done this but still get that same issue above.

Any suggestions? A missing dependency (hopefully!)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249829/error-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type-java-time-localdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this I removed all annotations from above my LocalDateTime objects in my models. For example:

> @NotNull
>
> private LocalDateTime dateTime;

to

> //@NotNull --commented out to demonstrate the removal. You should actually delete this.
>
> private LocalDateTime dateTime;

I then deleted the tables that Hibernate had generated from previous rebuild using Joda Time.

The solution was, in part, inspired by:
http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/
in the conclusion where the author states:

> This makes them even easier to use than the old java.util.Date because *you don’t have to add any additional annotations.*

There is serious lesson to be learnt here though; Ensure you database is compatible with your updated model. For me deleting it was enough, for the unit tests. But when 'going live' the database will need to me updated in a more careful way, not nuking the entire thing!