# LocalDate field validation does not work on DTO

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot

I'm doing some testing with field validation using a dto and annotating a LocalDate variable with @NotEmpty on a Spring boot api, however, I'm getting this error:

`javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.time.LocalDate'. Check configuration for 'dateBirth'`

The annotation library is javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty, had tried with javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty, however, so the annotation was marked as deprecated.

Declaration of the variable:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Campo Data de Nascimento é obrigatório")
private LocalDate dateBirth;
```

Is it necessary to add some dependency in pom.xml or something?

Comment: I think this link can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249829/error-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type-java-time-localdate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Doc](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty.html) says `@NotEmpty` supports only type of `CharSequence`, `Collection`, `Map`, or `Array`, so `LocalDate` doesn't fall into any of these type. For null check you should just use a `@NotNull` as it validates against any type. There is also `@Past` that validates if a date is in the past (in your case `dateBirth`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using @NotNull.

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Past;

public class cname
{
  @Past @NotNull
  private LocalDate bdate;
  ...
```